# How to manage EC2 via Drupal

Tags: 7

I would like to manage a couple of EC2 instances with Drupal, so instances as entities would be nice (to build a UI, tag them etc). Is there anything in that direction already?

I am looking for:
- Starting Instances
- Stopping Instances
- retrieving and storing the latest network configuration (ip changes everytime you shutdown and start an instance).

Thank you

Comment: you are probably looking for this: http://www.aegirproject.org/ I haven't used it for myself but I don't think it come with EC2 integration. But it should work well with normal VPS architecture.

Comment: Other way around I think @AyeshK (OP wants to manage EC2 instances from within a Drupal site by the looks of it)

Comment: yep. I want to manage ec2 instances within a drupal site.